# Vim bufdo with arguments?

Tags: vim

How can I run a certain command on only specific buffers (a list of buffer names, or a buffer name pattern etc) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for `:argdo`. Populate the arglist via `:args`. Then do `:argdo {cmd}` to run `{cmd}` on each of the files in the arglist.

```
:args *.c
:argdo %s/FOO/BAR/ge|update
```

To see all this in action take a look at some of these [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episodes:

- [Meet the arglist](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/meet-the-arglist/)
- [Populating the arglist](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/populating-the-arglist/)
- [Using :argdo to change multiple files](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/using-argdo-to-change-multiple-files/)
- [Project-wide find and replace](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/project-wide-find-and-replace/)

For more help see:

```
:h :args
:h :argdo
```